# Modules using react and webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

Looking for a good way to bundle CSS using Webpack with React and keep each component stylesheet in a separate file.

Component.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './Component.css'
```

Component2.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './Component2.css'
```

Right now my webpack config looks like this:

```
test: /\.css$/,
use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
        plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')]
    }}]
```

This way I'm able to separate each CSS file but ends up with a style-tag for each component.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I find [node-sass package](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) usefull. Install that using npm/yarn and add these lines to `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
"build-css": "node-sass src/ -o src/",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
"start": "node scripts/start.js watch-css",
...
}
```

Than whenever you create independent  SASS file, it will be compiled.